# Unit test factory method for object with dependencies

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I'm new in unit testing.

Its suggested to use Factory method to create instance of class under test for maintainability reasons.

Like:

```
public class StringCalculatorTests
    {
        [Fact]
        public void Add_EmptyString_ReturnZero()
        {
            var calculator = CreateCalculator();

            int result = calculator.Add("");

            result.Should().Be(0);
        }

        private static StringCalculator CreateCalculator()
        {        
          //Some difficult object creation
          var logger = Substitute.For<ILogger>();
          var calculator = new StringCalculator(logger);
          calculator.Initialize();
          return calculator;
        }
    }
```

Everything nice: if API changes - i will change StringCalculator creation only in one place, not in every tests.

But what if i need to change a return value for some method of `ILogger`. Or I will use `ILogger` not as  **stub** but as a **mock**:

```
 [Fact]
public void Add_EmptyString_LogAboutEmptyInput()
{
  var loggerMock = Substitute.For<ILogger>();
  var calculator = new StringCalculator(loggerMock);
  calculator.Initialize();

  calculator.Add("");

  logger.Received("Empty input.");
}
```

Now i can't use factory method, and if there are changes in API - i should go through my tests to change it.

I thought about property injection - but it may be not good local default for ILogger for example.
(i know - we usually have good default for logger, but it can be some another dependency)

I thought about optional parameters for factory method. But it seems to have logic. It's very simple but still logic.

Is there any good approach to solve this? Or it's good enough and it's a common situation to create instance just in class when we need it?

Comment: I don't believe you'll find a silver-bullet solution for this. The factory pattern allows you to abstract away the inner workings of your calculator, yet in tests where you specifically need to verify how those work, you can no longer abstract them away. You might find a specific solution that works in your particular case (like you said you have a good default logger), but I doubt a good generic solution exists (would love to know it if one does :) ).

Comment: I believe you are right. It seems to depend on case..

Answer (score 0):

You can overload your factory method to accept a mock logger.

```
private static StringCalculator CreateCalculator(ILogger logger)
{        
    var calculator = new StringCalculator(logger);
    calculator.Initialize();
    return calculator;
}
```

Then you can create your mock logger in the test (possibly a separate factory method for the logger if the same mocking is used in multiple tests)

```
[Fact]
public void Add_EmptyString_LogAboutEmptyInput()
{
  var loggerMock = //whatever code you need to set up your mock
  var calculator = CreateCalculator(loggerMock);

  calculator.Add("");

  logger.Received("Empty input.");
}
```

Comment: The con is now we have to support two methods, but i believe even with this con, it's better solution than optional parameters.